# Unresolved symbols when adding videoInput library to QtCreator project

Tags: c++, qt, linker

I am trying to use QtCreator and adding videoInput library (http://www.muonics.net/school/spring05/videoInput/) to the project. Original project is a simple form with no widgets yet (Qt Widget type). Until I add videoInput, everything compiles and runs ok.

When I add videoInput as library (via QtCreator GUI "Add library" option), the project does not compile: I am getting unresolved symbol error. When adding library, I choose "External library", point to .lib file as the library file, and point to .h file as the include path.
I am using Windows environment, QT 5.5.0 MSVC2013 64bit.
This is what my .pro file looks like after that:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../videoInput-master/compiledLib/vs2012/ -lvideoInput
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../videoInput-master/compiledLib/vs2012/ -lvideoInputd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../videoInput-master/compiledLib/vs2012/ -lvideoInput

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../videoInput-master/videoInputSrcAndDemos/libs/videoInput
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../videoInput-master/videoInputSrcAndDemos/libs/videoInput
```

Any idea how to fix the linking problem?

Comment: What does the lib export? If it exposes a C++ api, you'll need to match the Visual Studio version with all the libraries you use, or build the lib yourself (if you have access to the source code). 
  
 
 LE: And also you need to match the 32/64 bits, those 2 can't be linked together.

Comment: I'm glad you resolved the problem yourself.  SUGGESTION: In the future, please include the error text in your post - that would definitely help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I did re-build the lib with the same environment. However, that did not fix the issue. I looked into the error message closer and it turned out that I needed to link standard Windows libs (ole32.lib and oleaut32.lib) from C:\Windows\System32\ folder. That appears to have fixed the compiler issue for me.